# Limit definition when x tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

Using the limit definition, show that:

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+7}{3x^2+2}=0$

I get blocked when I use the equation:

[Formal definition of limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVabf.png)

if I apply the equation would look like this:

| x - ∞ | < ð → | $\frac{x+7}{3x^2+2}-0 < ε)$

Comment: In fact, somewhere in your book there should be the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty}$, which is different from that one.

Comment: Definition of limit for $x\to \infty$ is little bit different from the usual one. Are you aware of it? May be you should first consult some books or wiki.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I was not aware of this. I'm going to look for information about it, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition you give is for $x$ tending to $x_0$. The definition when $x$ tends to $\infty$ is:

**Definition** $f(x)$ tends to $L$ as $x$ tends to $ \infty$ if and only if $$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0 \ \mbox{ such that} \ \forall x \ \mbox{where} \ x>\delta, \\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Can you use this to solve the question?